# How to disable Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the Bootstrap datatimepicker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I'd like to disable the datetimepicker on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'
    });
});

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have tried `$('#datetimepicker1').prop('disabled', true)` and `$('#datetimepicker1').disable()` from (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#disable). Neither work. So what is the best way to do it?

Comment: you could just set the display: none; on your div if you would like a quick solution

Comment: That is not a good solution because the user can just set the display to appear and mess up the logic

Answer (score 3):

try the following code  `$('#datetimepicker1 > .form-control').prop('disabled', true);`
 please check the link https://jsfiddle.net/komal10041992/DTcHh/32829/

Comment: I am using a `datetimepicker` not a daterangerpicker

Comment: Thanks, where should this code be added? After the datetimepicker is initialized?

Comment: No need to add manually `disabled` property, the component has a [`disable()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#disable) function. In your fiddle, the user can click on calendar icon and open the datetimepicker anyway.

Comment: But still you can click calendar icon and choose date

Answer (score 3):

You were close to solution, you have to use [`disable()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#disable), but you have to remember that, as [docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/) says:

> **Note** All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g. `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()`

So you have to add `.data("DateTimePicker")` to your `$('#datetimepicker1').disable()`.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'
});

//To Disable use disable() function 
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").disable();
//To Enable use enable() function 
//$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").enable();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'
    }).find("input:first").prop("disabled", true);
});
```